# Calculate the starting position of a turning aircraft with inertial force to make it stop at desired position and heading

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, algorithm, movement-prediction

Continued from the answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121002/how-do-i-calculate-paths-for-objects-with-limited-acceleration/121016#121016), I have some problem when the aircraft in my game has inertial forces after going forward and turning itself. To illustrate, from the following image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds84n.jpg) the aircraft is moving from the point `A -> B -> C'-> D`. I planned to maneuver the aircraft from the point `C'` which is the point that would make the aircraft stop at the point `D` after turning with its full performance (using minimum turning radius).

[image: Path ABCD with error handling]

The question is how do I calculate the position of the point `C'` to make the aircraft roughly stop at the point `D` with the desired position and heading (It is roughly since there is also an inertial force after stopping the aircraft's engine.)?

Any suggestions and answers would be appreciated.

Comment: To answer this, we'll need to know the control model of your aircraft. How do you integrate its motion parameters into a new position and velocity? With this in hand, we can solve for the movement inputs that arrive at the desired position and velocity.

Comment: To control the aircraft, I use Rigidbody.AddForce(_force_) and Rigidbody.AddTorque(_torque_). Those two parameters (_force_ and _torque_) are calculated from maximum forward, maneuvering, and turning propulsion of the engine. For example, _force_ = _maxForwardPropulsion_ * _ratio_ (_ratio_ is either 0,1,or -1)

Comment: Edit: The ratio I mentioned above can be either 0,1, or -1 for every type of propulsion (forward, maneuvering, and turning propulsion), and the aircraft can choose to use any of the propulsion at the same time (e.g., it can choose to use turning propulsion only, or maneuvering and turning propulsion only, or all three).

Comment: With that control model, your turning radius is not necessarily a true circle as shown here or in the linked answer (that question used a control model with a minimum turning radius). Here your radius can shrink as you slow down, making less forward progress per degree of turning. This gets much harder to analyze.